# Why was the library full of books?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

I understand (though [with a little difficulty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/221535/7885)) that taking Captain Archer out his original timeline

> caused the Federation to be never created.

But how could this fact cause that 31st century library to be full of paper books instead of their electronic counterparts? Or, actually, how it was possible at all?

These devices were used on regular, day-to-day basis even in the 22nd century (they're in fact used today and were used when the series was created) so I see no point in claiming that alteration of history, as depicted in ["Shockwave. Part II" episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shockwave,_Part_II_(episode)), could cause such effects.

What am I missing?

Comment: My local library is full of books despite the existence of ebooks.

Comment: This isn't a good explanation, IMHO, because you have decided it to contain paper books and that is fine with you. While clear time agent's surprise says that it wasn't meant to be full of paper books. I am asking for a connection between these two events -- how can one cause the second one.

Comment: I suspect it's supposed to imply that technology has regressed

Comment: Much like the other questions you've just posted about this timeline and episode, we could only possibly speculate. Why not use your imagination to come up with your own personal answer! Then move on with watching the episode.

Comment: Much like the other questions I have just posted, I was asking, if a given issue or problem is answered directly in the episode (and I have just missed that explanation) or is it just a speculation. Years ago I've been asking similar questions here and that questions were OK. Seems not that asking about whether something is explained in the episode or not, is prohibited here or is a personal problem for someone. Pity.

Comment: This question is not an opinion. NO ELECTRICITY = NO DIGITAL DEVICES.  Daniels gave the answer. Please reopen the question

Comment: I don't really see how that question is opinion-based. Voted to reopen.