# Why was the future destroyed?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

I understand (though [with a little difficulty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/221535/7885)) that taking Captain Archer out of his original timeline

> caused the Federation to never be created.

But where is the connection between this and the fact that

> 31st century's Earth was a totally destroyed planet?

or, actually, how was it possible at all?

Is there any explanation in ["Shockwave. Part II" episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shockwave,_Part_II_(episode)), that I am maybe missing, that explains the connection between these two events?

Comment: Whale probe, I expect. Or VGER. Really any one of a dozen things that the Enterprise stopped from getting to Earth.

Comment: If I am getting this episode correct, the destruction of 31st century was not caused by Enterprise returning to home and stopping its mission, but by taking Captain Archer out of his original timeline. Enterprise could continue (then or within next 10-20 years) with any different captain, I think. Daniels says that he was ordered to do so and that this fact caused a destruction. I am asking only for a connection between these two events -- if that can be explained.

Comment: The Enterprise Valorum referred to was one of the later NCC-1701s, not the NX-01

Comment: No Federation, no NCC-1701 (a, b, c or bloody d) which means no stopping the Romulans at Khitomer, no Organian Peace Treaty, no Neutral Zone, etc etc

Comment: Vote for reopening - even if we can't (?) pinpoint the one thing that could destroy Earth, providing a list of possible catastrophic events (as described in the show) would be a valid answer.

Comment: @Yasskier - no it wouldn't it be speculative opinion :)

Comment: @NKCampbell if there was a question "What Earth-destroying events have been prevented by Enterprise/Federation" - it would be valid. The OP question is a variation of it - while we can't pinpoint ONE event, we know about confirmed few that were prevented.

Comment: Frankly saying, I completely don't understand all those people who voted to close this question. It is by no mean speculative-open question. It strikely asks: if the connection between these two events is explained in the episode. So the perfectly valid (as for me) answer is: "No, this is not explained in the eposiode and the possible connections are to vague to discuss in the format of this site".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have no way of knowing. There is no TV show or book that chronicles the events of *almost a thousand years of history* in that altered timeline. Any number of disasters could have ensued. Naively we could guess that V'Ger or the Whale Probe might be responsible — entities that were stopped from harming Earth by Federation elements — or we could just make up some story that an unaligned Earth would be much more likely to come up against significant threats in the future. The Romulan War? Or something that happened in 2800... *we could only wildly guess*.

Comment: As I explained in a comment to the question itself, this is the kind of answer I was looking for, so I have up-voted it and accepted. However, I completely agree with TheLethalCarror. What I have learnt from my 5+ years history on SE, VTC+answer is a bad behaviour and a completely unclear message. You shouldn't answer a question you find too poor or too wrong to exist.